# WAMP equivalent for JSP

Tags: jsp, wamp

I already have WAMP server installed in my system which makes life much easier :-).

So can anyone tell me what is the WAMP server equivalent for JSP?

Comment: Do you mean you want to run JSP via WAMP? Tomcat is your answer.

Comment: Tomcat is just a servelet container equivalent to Apache in WAMP. I want to know what is the WAMP equivalent for JSP.

Answer (score 7):

WAMP basically stands for "Windows, [Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/), [MySQL DB Server](http://mysql.com/) and [PHP](http://php.net/)". It's just a convenience software bundle for the lazy (pardon me ;) ) who doesn't want (or doesn't know how) to download/install/configure each separately.

The JSP/Servlet equivalent would look like "[Apache Tomcat Server](http://tomcat.apache.org), [MySQL DB Server](http://mysql.com)". The JSP support is already builtin Tomcat as being a JSP/Servlet implementation (also known as *servlet container*), while Apache HTTP Server doesn't by default support PHP, hence there's no need to substitute "PHP" with "JSP". Windows is irrelevant here as both Java and MySQL can just run at almost all platforms, so it's left away.

For JSP/Servlet you don't necessarily need the Apache HTTP Server as Apache Tomcat is already a full fledged webserver. But if you want to run *both* PHP and JSP at one webserver for some reasons (which I don't really recommend though), then you need to add [Apache Tomcat Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/) (also known as `mod_jk`) to Apache HTTP Server instance so that it can forward JSP/Servlet-specific requests to any Apache Tomcat Server which is installed at same machine.

If you already have WAMP installed and would like to make use of the same MySQL DB Server, then you don't need to download/install it separately. Just Tomcat would be enough and if necessary also the mod_jk for Apache HTTP Server.

To learn more about Tomcat and JSP/Servlet, I can recommend to dive in the [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/) and the [Marty Hall's Coreservlets.com tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html) respectively. The latter also covers Tomcat and Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat, despite all its downsides.

Comment: Downsides? What are you talking about?

Comment: It has some buggy features such as per virtual host logging. But it is really good. I do like it.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat.

You can also use xampp, which will roll your lamp stack and tomcat into one management interface (just for starting and stopping the servers).

Answer (score 0):

Wamp uses Apache HTTP Server, if you want something similar there is [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) for servlets. But it is as easy as WAMP since you have to do a configuration.

Here is an **easy** way of **[configuration](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/)**

Which IDE do you use? If you are using Netbeans, it has Apache Tomcat and Glassfish bundled. So you don't have to configure it (actually during setup you do a small configuration which is very very easy)

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server#Java_application_servers) is a list of Java Application Servers.

Comment: Apache is a software company name. You maybe meant to say "Apache HTTP Server" in the first place.

Comment: Actually it is a software foundation but you are right. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using NetBeans with the bundled servers it will integrate nicely with the IDE and make it simple to use much like WAMP. You can then use either Tomcat or GlassFish. You can use either the Java flavor of NetBeans or the All.

[NetBeans Download](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html)

Comment: Netbeans is a development tool, not a webserver. You don't want to install Netbeans in a production server.

Comment: Yes but you shouldn't be using NetBeans in production, it is only a dev tool just the same as I would put WAMP in.