# Where does the Java EE folder go?

Tags: java, servlets

I just downloaded from: http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/download.html the Java(TM) Servlet API Specification Interface Classes 2.3

Inside this zip file I have the folder

- javax (folder)
- servlet (folder)
- http (folder)
- bunch of class files

Where do I put this? So I can call it from my Java program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The servlet-api.jar goes unmodified on your classpath while you develop your application.  The target deployment place (inside Tomcat or a full fledged Java EE server) provides its own version to your program so the development one you downloaded should not be part of what you deploy to the final location.

What is your deployment platform?

Comment: WAMP. I don't use Tomcat or Jetty. Should I switch?

Comment: Only if "WAMP" does not include a container capable of dealing with Java servlets.

Comment: I would suggest opening a new question if you find you need advice on choosing such a container.

Comment: @Dan: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032622/wamp-equivalent-for-jsp

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what this is, but if you want to run servlets you need a servlet/JSP engine.  I'd recommend Apache Tomcat or Jetty.  It will have all the JARs you need to run a web app.